# How do I find out what version of Apache or nginx web server is used in ElasticBeanStalk?

Tags: apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Following is what I see in Elastic BeanStalk

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hzlB.png

I'm going through Apache documentation to write Rewrite rules. But I'm confused which version I should read.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Log in via SSH and run:

```
$ httpd -v
```

> Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)

See also: [`eb ssh`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html)

---

If running Nginx, use:

```
$ nginx -v
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this on terminal, and it will return information about the server:

```
curl -sI https://anydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way -- check out your logs and search for Apache. I'm using Django and I see `Apache/2.4.37 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.7`. It appears a few times.

Answer (score 0):

On SSH or Putty try first

```
httpd -v
```

if any result appears

> Server version: Apache/***

that means you in Apache server.

```
Nginx -v
```

if any result similar to

```
Nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

then you can decide Nginx* or Apache*
because those commands only run apache and Nginx as follows,

in my scenario I'm using nginx 1.14.0 it shows me an error

httpd -v

> Command 'httpd' not found, did you mean:
>
> > command 'http' from snap http (1.0.0-1)   command 'xttpd' from deb
> >     xtide   command 'http' from deb httpie
> >     See 'snap info ' for additional versions.
>
> and also try

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
```